# JobScheduler jobs not starting when running app with the screen locked

Tags: java, android, multithreading, http, job-scheduling

I have been trying to make an app that works good with the doze feature in Android but the problem I've been getting is that when the phone (Android 6) has the screen recently locked and I run the app with Android Studio, the job never gets executed. After reading the documentation and seeing this Doze figure :
[image]
I expected to be given a window of time to make an HTTP request to update my app but I have waited at least 15 minutes and that never occurred.

The job is being created and scheduled in the onCreate method like this:

```
ComponentName componentName =
    new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), ConnectJobService.class);
jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(33, componentName)
    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
    .build();
int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo); //resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS > true
```

Here is my manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.xg.frequencytester">

    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat" >
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <service
            android:name=".ConnectJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
            />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: The first that comes in mind is to know if the service is registered in the manifest or if the internet permission is requested, can you please add yout AndroidManifest.xml relevant code?

Comment: Yes, the service is registered and  gets time to run when the device is unlocked. I updated my question with the manifest.

Comment: I'm so sorry! I assume this question was about FirebaseJobDispatcher... I do recommend on using FirebaseJobDispatcher because is backward compatible, the Android jobs are not

Answer (score 0):

On Android 6, the Doze mode is not entered the second you turn off the screen, but [after an unspecified amount of time](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

> If a user leaves a device unplugged and stationary for a period of time, with the screen off, the device enters Doze mode.

Because of that, I suspect that this is not the problem. One possible option could be that `JobScheduler` is being affected by the CPU entering a low power mode a few seconds after the screen is turned off. (Related: [Keeping the Device Awake](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html))

From my experience, even when scheduling a task with the device unlocked and the screen on can be delayed for a few seconds, and because of that the case you're experiencing could be similar to this.

I would try playing with backoff and deadline. Notice that default backoff strategy is **exponential**:

```
ComponentName componentName =
    new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), ConnectJobService.class);
jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(33, componentName)
    .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
    .setOverrideDeadline(5000L)
    .setBackoffCriteria(500L, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
    .build();
int resultCode = jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo); //resultCode == JobScheduler.RESULT_SUCCESS > true
```

Notice that [default initial backoff](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#DEFAULT_INITIAL_BACKOFF_MILLIS) is 30000ms and [maximum](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.html#MAX_BACKOFF_DELAY_MILLIS) is 18000000ms (this is **5hrs**!).

Comment: You added a backoffCriteria which redefines when a failed job will be run (mine never starts) and I'm afraid the new overrideDeadline will ignore the requiredNetworkType as the documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html) says that it will make the job run even if other requirements aren't met. EDIT: I applied the new backoff criteria but my job didn't run.

Comment: As you say, override deadline will make the job, skipping the requirements. The objective is to have a last resort. I forced a low value to try to make it run soon to verify if that would work. About the backoff, my theory is that the job is scheduled, but maybe it fails to start in the first try. That's why I suggest to set a more reasonable backoff, to see if it finally runs. Finally, you could try to remove override deadline, as given is a deadline, it could cancel the job (I think it will not, but run the job as soon as is able to, but just in case...) Let me know if it helps.

Comment: The job runs when I use the setPeriodic method or if I use the setOverrideDeadline, and I agree with you that having a last resort execution is a good idea but I don't know why the job never prints the text I have at the start of the onStartJob with only the requiredNetworkType condition. I can only assume it is just not recognizing the wifi network when it is locked but I can explain why.

Comment: Ah, that would make sense. You should check if the WiFi gets disabled when screen is off in the WiFi Advanced settings.

Comment: I checked that and it was the case. Thanks for the help.